# Lua Store Multiple Strings in Single Table Element

Tags: lua

### -- Store Values from Commandline in Table element and print them back

--

```
my_table = {}

local my_arg_count = (#arg)
print (my_arg_count)


for count = 1,my_arg_count do
    print ("count:"..count..":")
    if my_table[1] ~= nil then
        my_val = my_table[1]
        print ("my val:"..my_val..":")
        my_table[1] = print (my_val,"\n",arg[count])
    else
        print ("my table is nil. . . on noes!")
        my_table[1] = arg[count]
    end
end

for i=1,table.maxn(my_table) do
    print ("Index: "..i..":")
    print (my_table[i])
end
```

The above is code from a test; I want to be able to take multiple arbitrary text strings as store them in a single table element.  Like so:

my_table["stuff_bob_says"] = "Blah blah"

Next I want to be able to add to the index "stuff_bob_says" so that:

stuff_bob_already_said = my_table["stuff_bob_says"]

my_table["stuff_bob_says"] = "stuff_bob_already_said" + "yakety smackety"

Is this even possible? I think it should be with strings. . . . but the output from the test is not quite right.

Comment: Don't put `"` around `stuff_bob_already_said`, also you can just do `my_table["stuff_bob_says"] = my_table["stuff_bob_says"] .. "," .. "yakety smackety"`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.  Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I correctly understand your issue than you want to add a string to a existing table entry. This can easly be done using:

```
my_table["stuff_bob_says"] = my_table["stuff_bob_says"] .. "next string to add"
```

This will only work when the table entry already exists and is a string.

To concat mutliple strings from a table into a single table entry this would look like:

```
input = { "a", "b", "c" }
output = { }

for _, text in pairs(input) do
    output["key"] = output["key"] .. text
end

-- use output
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Not sure why I had so much trouble conceptualizing this.